# Popular posts by specified date ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please help me to implement actions for posts_controller such as: top posts by 1 day, week, month and all time. Can I solve this by using Scopes such as : `scope :top_week, lambda {order("posts.view DESC").where("created_at < ?", DateTime.now - 1.week)}` and how can I create links to them in my view file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your question into several parts:

1 - create variables inside your controller

```
@posts = Post.all
@top_post_weekly = @posts.top_weekly
```

then create your scopes inside post model

```
scope :top_weekly, -> { your query }
```

then put them into your views

```
<% @top_posts_weekly.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.text %>
<% end %>
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

define the scope in the model file as needed, and take a look at the has_scope gem https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope which is used in the controller to call the scope method.